# FPDF has already been output using FPDF in Yii framework

Tags: php, yii, fpdf

i have problem with FPDF in Yii Framework, i wan't to show number read as text

SATU JUTA TIGA RATUS RIBU RUPIAH FPDF error: Some data has already been output, can't send PDF file

```
$a = array ($jmltagihan, $jmltagihan1, $jmltagihan2, $jmltagihan3);
$b = array_sum($a);
$c = number_format($b,2,',','.');
Yii::import("application.components.Terbilang");
$terbilang = new Terbilang();
$terbilang->rupiah($b);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try cleaning the buffer directly before you output the pdf:

```
while(@ob_end_clean()) {}
$a = array ($jmltagihan, $jmltagihan1, $jmltagihan2, $jmltagihan3);
$b = array_sum($a);
$c = number_format($b,2,',','.');
Yii::import("application.components.Terbilang");
$terbilang = new Terbilang();
$terbilang->rupiah($b);
```

*If this doesn't work try moving the `while(@ob_end_clean()) {}` more and more to the bottom of your code.*

**Explanation:** Frameworks often have rendered layout and stuff already at this point so you need to clean all the buffer levels with `ob_end_clean()` so the pdf won't get corrupted.

Comment: Where exactly are you calling FPDF?

Comment: i call FPDF like this : require_once ("protected/extensions/fpdf17/fpdf.php"); 
 $pdf = new FPDF(); 
 $pdf->AddPage();

Comment: Try adding `while(@ob_end_clean()) {}` right before outputting the pdf

Comment: i give that and that's works but how i can call output of $terbilang ?

Comment: What do you mean exactly?

Comment: i adding ob_end_clean(); 
my PDF can show against, but i adding $terbilang->rupiah($b);
it's error again, how i can call $terbilang->rupiah($b); without i getting error

Comment: error say like this "SATU JUTA TIGA RATUS RIBU RUPIAH FPDF error: Some data has already been output, can't send PDF file (output started at C:\xampp\htdocs\www\protected\components\Terbilang.php:6)"

Comment: Then also add it at this file before line 6

Comment: Thank you i have trying against with javascript and working, thank you very much for your answer my question

Comment: sorry i can vote because i new, but i can check this answer is true

Answer (score 0):

**Some data has already been output, can't send PDF file**.

This kind of error happens when you have *another* error before your code. Since errors also cause output to be sent to the screen, (like a warning or a notice, even), you can't send anything else.

Try commenting out the part where you actually send the PDF file and you'll probably some other error before that. You can then correct (or suppress) that and you'll be able to send your PDF file.